# In what cases mongoexport can be used?

Tags: json, mongodb, bson, mongoexport

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), it says to avoid mongoexport on BSON datatypes

> **WARNING**
> Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance
> production backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data
> types, because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported
> by BSON. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup
> Methods for this kind of functionality.

Created a collection with name "testCollection"

```
 > db.testCollection.insert({title: 'MongoDB Overview',
... description: 'MongoDB is magical database',
...    by: 'by newbie',
...    url: 'http://www.mongodb_cannot_understand_mongoexport.com',
...    tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
...    likes: 100});

> db.testCollection.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59524e6412d3ef3c879c267a"),
    "title" : "MongoDB Overview",
    "description" : "MongoDB is magical database",
    "by" : "by newbie",
    "url" : "http://www.mongodb_cannot_understand_mongoexport.com",
    "tags" : [
        "mongodb",
        "database",
        "NoSQL"
    ],
    "likes" : 100
}
```

Executing the below commands gives type as object and String,

> typeof db.testCollection.findOne()._id; **output : object**
>
> typeof db.testCollection.findOne().title; **output : string**

If running mongoexport on the above collection may or mayn't guarantee the preservation of data as it contains the data types string and object.
(I doubt any documents will not have string, objectID datatype)

In that case mongoexport should not be used at all from [this list of bson types link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

My question is

In what cases mongoexport can be used with a example collection ?

NOTE:
**I want to use mongoexport, mongodump is not an option**

Comment: Duplicate of [Which MongoDB types are not preserved by mongoimport/mongoexport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554640/which-mongodb-types-are-not-preserved-by-mongoimport-mongoexport), which has an authoritative answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What that paragraph in the documenation means is that, with mongoexport/mongoimport, there's **no guarantee** that data in the restored database will match exactly what was in the original source. This is because JSON does not natively support many of BSON data types, such as Date, MinKey, ObjectId, etc. So mongoexport has to do workarounds to export at least *something* for those types. This is how it exports ObjectId fields, for example:

```
"_id": {"$oid": "531701fdb9e3b40002000002"}
```

To backup/restore your data *reliably*, use mongodump/mongorestore.

> In what cases mongoexport can be used with a example collection ?

When you want to get a *somewhat* human-readable snapshot of your data. JSON is also very well supported in most every language, so you can use mongoexport to dump data for crunching with python's scientific libs, or something like that.

Comment: Edited the question :), I cannot use mongodump/mongorestore

Comment: @forum.test17: well, that's your problem. You either use mongodump or forget about reliable backup restore. Which is to say, mongoexport/mongoimport _should not_ crash, but they can mangle your data.

Comment: so u meant to  mongoexport/mongoimport is of no use even for smallest collection of one record as in the above example :(, if so how come mongodb have included these binaries after all :(

Comment: not understood completely, will wait for while for other answers, if not will accept urs :)

Comment: Using [Extended JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554640/which-mongodb-types-are-not-preserved-by-mongoimport-mongoexport/56613599#56613599), mongoexport does preserve type information.

Answer (score 1):

That warning is actually obsolete! I've just started a discussion with the MongoDB team, and they're planning to [remove it](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12805).

**Mongoexport now uses [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554640/which-mongodb-types-are-not-preserved-by-mongoimport-mongoexport/56613599#56613599) to preserve type information.**