# Which MongoDB types are not preserved by mongoimport/mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb, types, mongoimport, mongoexport

The [documentation for `mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) has this scary warning,

> Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance production backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson) data types, because [JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-json) can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup Methods for this kind of functionality.

The page then goes on to say,

> To preserve type information, mongoexport and mongoimport uses the [strict mode representation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for certain types.

**What exactly are the [types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) that mongoexport still doesn't represent properly, in spite of the "strict mode representation"?**

Asking because `mongorestore` has an extremely annoying limitation: it [doesn't support an `upsert` option](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-121), which makes it impossible to use for synchronizing collections where only a few documents get updated. You'd have to `--drop` the whole collection before restoring it entirely from scratch, which can be very time consuming for large collections, especially if text indexes need to be recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the warning against mongoimport/export is obsolete. It's still a good idea to use mongodump/restore for speed, but **mongoexport preserves type information using the [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/vtz6W4SfgH8) format**. For example, a Date field is no longer silently converted to text, but instead to:

```
{ "$date": "<date>" }
```

where `<date>` is the ISO-8601 `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mmm<+/-Offset>` representation of the date. Regular expressions are converted to

```
{ "$regex": "<sRegex>", "$options": "<sOptions>" }
```

etc. These textual representation of the document fields are parsed by mongoimport, restoring the original types. See [BSON Data Types and Associated Representations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson-data-types-and-associated-representations) for more information.

The [warning will hopefully be removed soon](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12805).