# Find out all types used in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, types, aggregation-framework

Let's say you want to use mongoexport/import to update a collection (for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554640/which-mongodb-types-are-not-preserved-by-mongoimport-mongoexport). You should make sure the types in the collection are JSON-safe.

How can one determine all the types used in all documents of a collection, including within array elements, using the aggregation framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in combination with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html).

I think something like this should get you started:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
      types: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$$CURRENT" },
          in: { $type: [ "$$this.v" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Note it is not recursive and it would not go deep into the values of the arrays since I am not also sure how many levels you want to go deep and even what is the desired output. So hopefully that is a good start for you.

You can see that aggregation with provided input with various types [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S_aeL0Dyf1I).

Comment: Thank you. Interesting start. Any idea how to recurse at all, [e.g. one level in objects](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dBHUC0BVA9G) or arrays?